# How to use iptables to forward all traffic on port 80 to another proxy?

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, http

I would like to forward all http traffic to another proxy server running on the same machine?

How to use iptables to forward all traffic on port 80 to another proxy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to redirect *incoming* traffic to another local port? Or do you want to send *outgoing* traffic via a transparent HTTP proxy program? Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: I would like to forward all HTTP requests from port 80 to another proxy running on localhost, port 8080.